# HTTP url parameter with empty value is equal with no key?

Tags: http

This 2 Url is same?

- http://www.example.com/list?key1=value1
- http://www.example.com/list?key1=value1&key2=

I wonder parameter with empty value can be considered like no key(also no value) in http protocol.

Answer (score 1):

No, the urls are not the same. The value for `key2` is the empty string. How the server interprets this value has nothing to do with HTTP.